# Tagging a phrase to learn a classifier using NLTK in Python

Tags: python, nlp, classification, nltk

I have a phrase like this one:

```
Apple iPhone 5 White 16GB
```

and I want to tag in this way

```
B M C S
```

where
B=Brand (Apple)
M=Model (iPhone 5)
C=Color (White)
S=Size (Size)

A classifier must learn the sequence pattern... I think that I will use SVM or CRF.

My question is what is the best way to tag a phrase like this? I will use the NLTK library for python.

What you think of `{Apple}\B {iPhone 5}\M....`? What is the best way?

Is there also a way to use a seed dictionary (of brands for example) to let NLTK automatic tagging a list of phrases for me?

Comment: You can manually tag the sequences using the tag set that you already have decided. While training on the data set, you can use the seed dictionary to improve the performance of a classifer you choose for training.

Comment: I think the question is about the annotation format. The format is usually determined by the implementation of the classifier you use. You probably need to verticalise the text (one token per line) and put the annotation in a separate column. As you will have multi-word expression (like iPhone 5, which the tokeniser will tear apart), you might need to use the BIO tags (besides the classes you are interested in) to mark beginning and ending of the spans.